# Facebook like button shows 0 like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I waited for 1 month before posting this question.

On 2 my websites facebook button doesn't work, it shows 0 likes even if I click like and reload the page. On another website (always https) it works.

What it can be?

Example, doesn't work here:
https://www.intherimini.com/en/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=185407924984797";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.intherimini.com/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" style="padding:3px 10px 3px 30px;"></div>
```

On another website (incinqueterre.com) it works fine with the same code (only href and appID is changed). The both App have the same parameters....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.
If your website has more than 1 language and the initial page just redirects you to your language page - **it's not possible to set like button to the domain name**. You have to set it to the page without redirect.